# Differences between compiled dalvik binaries

Tags: dalvik

I'm compiling dalvik on Android 4.1 with both host and target set to x86. The make command is:

```
make dalvikvm core ext framework android.policy services
```

However, there are multiple compiled binaries:

```
out/host/linux-x86/bin/dalvikvm
out/host/linux-x86/bin/dalvik
out/target/product/generic_x86/system/bin/dalvikvm
out/target/product/generic_x86/symbols/system/bin/dalvikvm
```

But the target versions don't work. When run, they show:

```
bash: ./dalvikvm: No such file or directory
```

This error is so strange that, I mean, the file is just there.

Could anyone please tell me which one is the compiled result? I mean, if I make some modification to dalvik source, which one will contain the modified result? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a linkage issue. The host version is linked against the normal host libc, but the target versions are linked against the android libc that lives in /system/lib on the device, which your host ld knows nothing about.

You might try something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<android_root>/out/target/product/generic_x86/system/lib out/target/product/generic_x86/symbols/system/bin/dalvikvm
```

Although I'm not entirely sure if that would work

Comment: Thanks. But the error notice is the same as above. The file(dalvikvm) is there, has non-zero size, can be objdumped, but cannot be executed. Why the error notice is "no such file or directory"?

Comment: That's what you usually see on linker errors. If you run ldd on it, it should tell you specifically what dependencies it can't find.

Comment: ldd on it also shows *No such file or directory*. It's strange because there are libraries compiled in ./out/target/product/generic_x86/system/lib, so I expect dalvikvm to be linked against them.